# How large can the jumps of $ \frac1\pi\arg\zeta\left(\frac12+iT\right) $ be?

Tags: riemann-zeta

It is known that the function
$
\frac1\pi\arg\zeta\left(\frac12+iT\right)
$
is continuous,  except when T is the imaginary part of a Zeta zero.

In that case the jump of this function  can only be large at Zeta zeros with high multiplicity.  Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you define it, many different branches..

- Under the RH there is a branch of $\text{arg } \zeta(s)$ which is continuous on $\Re(s)\in (1/2,1)$,

letting $$\text{arg }\zeta(1/2+it)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{arg }\zeta(1/2+it+\epsilon)$$ then yes there is a $+ k\pi$ jump at each non-trivial zero of multiplicity $k$.

- If you don't believe in the RH then there is a branch of $\text{arg } \zeta(s)$ continuous **on $\Re(s) > 1$ and on every horizontal strip without zeros**,

in which case $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{arg }\zeta(1/2+it+\epsilon)$ has a $+ k\pi$ jump at each zero of multiplicity $k$ on $\Re(s)=1/2$ and a $+2k\pi$ jump at each $t$ such that there are $k$ zeros (counted with multiplicity) on $\Im(s)=t,\Re(s) > 1/2$.